# layout_width and layout_weight - performance

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#80939393"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
     >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/column1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />


    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#90909090"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column2"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/column_title_2" />

    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#90909090"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/column3_container" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column3"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/column_title_3" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sort_column_3"
            android:layout_width="20dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/solid_up" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#90909090"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/column4_container" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column4"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/column_title_4" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sort_column_4"
            android:layout_width="20dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#90909090"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/column5_container" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/column5"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/column_title_5" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sort_column_5"
            android:layout_width="20dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#90909090"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column6"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/column_title_6" />

</LinearLayout>
    <View android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#90909090"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
    </ListView>
    <View android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#90909090"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting two warnings in my eclipse over performance.

`Nested weights are bad for performance` when using `android:layout_weight="1"` **and** `Use a layout_width of 0dip instead of 50dip for better performance`

Can anyone say me why its throwing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it is this:
Since you are using `layout_weight` that is superseding `layout_width`. So essentially the `layout_width` is getting ignored. But it isn't technically getting all the way ignored, instead the system is applying `layout_width="50dp"` and then going back and doing the math to apply `layout_weight="1"` so it is doing twice as much work. It is telling you to use 0dp so that you avoid doing the (unnecessary) work.

**EDIT**

Your second issue `Nested weights are bad for performance` is because you have a weight on your `LinearLayout` and a weight on the `TextView` which is *inside of* that `LinearLayout` hence they are "nested". The warning is telling you that setting up your layout in that manner can be bad for performance. Ideal fix would be probably to work out some way to accomplish the look you want using `RelativeLayout` and not using weight at all. But in reality unless you specifically noticing or hearing reports of poor performance you can probably leave it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `weight` attribute, it calculates the width for that view based on the value for `weight`. If you don't set the width of the view to 0dp, it calculates the width again, which is unnecessary. So if you use  `weight`, and then width to 0dp it only has to calculate the size once.

---

For the nested weight warning

```
android:layout_width="70dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

remove the weight attribute here in this linearlayout

Comment: Can you change the TextView code on what it should actually be.

Comment: Just change 50dip to 0dip in `layout_width`

Comment: I did that, but its still showing "Nested weights are bad for performance"

Comment: @Kevin that is a different issue, means probably that you have a parent view that is also using weight. Can you edit your question and post the rest of your layout?

Comment: One "error" solved, halfway there ;) Are you sure that these are errors, not warnings?

Comment: @Tim: these are warnings... and FoamyGuy... i have updated my entire layout.

Comment: @Kevin see my edit for explanation of the nested weight thing.