# How to equally divide two buttons horizontally without using layout_weight?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two Buttons called btnBeginner and btnAdvanced.
I have divided these two Buttons equally by using the `layout_weight` property.  But the `layout_weight` is bad for performance.
Because of that, I would like to change my existing code - which is shown below.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLayoutBeginAdv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBeginner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@color/color_exam_btn_hlight"
            android:text="beginner"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdvanced"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@color/color_exam_btn_normal"
            android:text="advanced"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Please help me to do the same without using the `layout_weight` property.

Comment: `"But the layout_weight is bad for performance"` who said so?

Comment: @Sam if you don't want to use layout_weight use Relative Layout or Absolute Layout instead of Linear Layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT : [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.
consider using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) and associated layouts instead.**

Nested weights are bad for performance because :

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another
>   LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements
>   increase exponentially.

So in your case, weight will not create the performance problem. But still if you want to divide the layout into two equal parts without using weight, you can use [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Sample :

```
   android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBeginner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_exam_btn_hlight"
        android:text="beginner"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdvanced"    
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_exam_btn_normal"
        android:text="advanced"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Visit [this Github repo](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample) for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot....You taught me a new layout called "PercentRelativeLayout" which I did not even heard about it. God bless you dear!!!

Comment: @Sam I'm happy if I did any help. If you want to find more layout, check [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/51)

Answer (score 3):

I'd place a dummy View in the center of a RelativeLayout.
Then set a Button to the right of it and another one to the left of it.

Something like so

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Dummy in the center -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <!-- Left Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:toLeftOf="@id/dummy"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
    <!-- Right Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:toRightOf="@id/dummy"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `Space` instead of a dummy `View` for even better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `layout_width = "0dp"` for all the buttons in Linear Layout.

As **layout_weight**, superseding **layout_width**. So essentially the layout_width is getting ignored.

So basically you code should be like :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLayoutBeginAdv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBeginner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ...../>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdvanced"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ..... />

    </LinearLayout>
```

For more reference you should this link : 
[layout_width and layout_weight - performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766488/layout-width-and-layout-weight-performance)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use layout_weight use Relative Layout`

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are looking out to divide two buttons in single row using constraint layout then below is the example for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context="com.com.schooldemo.example.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonD"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonD"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="D"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonA" />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```