# Dividing RelativeLayout into 3 same part

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

In my layout, i have logo at top of the activity.
now I want to divide my relative layout into three same part to include 3 relative layout inside.
Is it possible to make weight for relative layout?
How I divide it into 3 same relative layout?

here is my code:

```
  <RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/logo"
           android:id="@+id/logo"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37561519/5392118) answer please. It might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

No RelativeLayout don't support weight, just use the Linear Layout, will give the expect result:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    orientation:"vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@drawable/logo"
                   android:id="@+id/logo"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@drawable/calender"
                   android:id="@+id/logo"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="0dp">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="0dp">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="0dp">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    orientation:"vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1/>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1/>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1/>

</LinearLayout>
```